# Replace single slash with double slash

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I have the below Apache Spark Dataframe `df_result` where it has one column `Name`.

```
df_result.repartition(1).write.option('header','true').option("delimiter","|").option("escape", "\\").mode("overwrite").csv(path)
```

In this column, the values are like below.

```
Name
.....
John
Mathew\M
```

In the second row, there is a `\` character. When I export this to csv using the above script, it generates the value as `Mathew\M` in the file. Ideally, I need the value as `Mathew\\M` in the file (ie, single `\` should be replaced with `\\`). Is there a way to do this using the `option` or any other ways?

Am using Apache Spark 3.2.1.

Comment: df_result["Name"] = df_result["Name"].str.replace("\\", "\\\\")

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Seems to work for me

```
df.withColumn('Name', regexp_replace('Name','\\\\',r'\1\\\\')).write.option('header','true').option("delimiter","|").option("escape", "\\").mode("overwrite").csv("/tmp/output/wk/bn.cv")
```

Comment: Can you please let me know why you are using 1 in between \

Comment: r'\1 replaces each of the previous group with itself.